# Is this statement about this continuous function correct?

Tags: calculus

Is it true that if $f^2$ is continuous, then $\lvert f \rvert$ is continuous?
Can I say that since $f^2 \geq 0$ then $\lvert f \rvert = \sqrt{f^2}$ and that indicates that $\lvert f \rvert$ is also continuous beacuse of the arithmetic property of continuous functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the square root function is continuous in its domain, and composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: And is it also correct to say that $\lvert f \rvert = \sqrt{f^2}$ ?

Comment: Yes. For every real number we have $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, so for every real function $f$ you also have $|f|=\sqrt{f^2}$.

Of course, things are completely different if we consider complex numbers.

Comment: Great!! Thanks ((: